# Is this QQ convex or concave?

Tags: r, descriptive-statistics, qq-plot, exponential-distribution

With my data I got this exponential QQplot :

[image]

is this QQplot convex or concave ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Convavity and convexity are property of *continuous* functions. The only continuous function in your plot is the line, which is of course both concave and convex.

Comment: I mean the blue curve (not the dark line)

Comment: there is no blue curve. There are only blue dots. Please check the definition of [continuous function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function)  and re-read my first comment.

Comment: so its convex or concave ? I think its concave but I am not sure. thanks in advance

Comment: what exactly do *you* mean by these words (convex/concave)? The usual definition of these terms do not apply to the blue dots in your image.

Comment: @user603 The idea of convexity extends even to discrete plots of this nature: they can be said to be convex or concave when every point lies on the boundary of the convex hull of all points.  (And in this sense, the illustration clearly is neither convex nor concave--but it is *approximately* concave.)  But Alex, why do you ask this question?  What is meaningful about it?

Comment: @whuber I want to modelling large claims using Extreme Value Theory. this is why I plot this exponential QQ plot first to have an idea about the tail

Comment: But what would concavity or convexity tell you about the tail?  Those properties seem completely irrelevant to tail behavior.

Comment: @whuber I mean the tail index xi

Comment: If you mean in the sense of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2357673/definition-of-tail-index-of-a-probability-distribution, the tail index has little to do with convexity of a QQ plot.  Certainly an asymptotic convexity can provide some information--but when the tail of the plot alternates between convex and concave behavior, approximating linearity--as yours does--then convexity is no longer a useful characterization.  If you're interested in the tail index, then please *ask about the tail index* rather than something that might turn out to be irrelevant.  You'll get better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

**Con-cave = Looks like a cave**

This is a  simple way to remember the difference: concave looks like a cave, and by process of elimination, convex is the other one.  Your plot of blue dots look roughly (but not exactly) concave.  The [strict definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function) for concavity of a series of points would require each of the points to be above the line intersecting any surrounding points.